# What does rank of a diagonal matrix tell you about the number of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I understand, if an $n × n$ matrix is diagonalizable, it needs $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. If the matrix has a rank of $1$ does it have $1$ non-zero eigenvalue?

Answer (score 3):

If a **diagonalizable** matrix has rank $1$, it has one nonzero eigenvalue.  Not true for non-diagonalizable matrices, e.g. for $$\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$